# Cargo registry update always fails

Tags: windows, rust, rust-cargo

I am having trouble building Rust programs on Windows. Everything builds fine until I add a dependency. Once a dependency is added I get the following trying to update the crates registry. Any ideas?

```
cargo build --verbose
        Updating registry `https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index`
           error Unable to update registry https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index

    Caused by:
      [2/-1] Could not open '.cargo/registry/index/github.com-88ac128001ac3a9a/bi/tt/bittorrent' for writing: Access is denied.
```

Comment: try to rename folder `c:\users\YORUSERNAME\.cargo\registry\index\github.com-88ac128001ac3a9a` and run it again

Comment: The actual folder in the could not open message is c:\users\YORUSERNAME\.cargo\registry\index\github.com-88ac128001ac3a9a. I omitted c:\users\username.

Comment: I know, but can you rename it VIA explorer? )

Comment: I did. I get the same error

Answer (score 0):

Your anti-virus software may be interfering with the operation. Try disabling your anti-virus software temporarily, or add an exception for the problematic folders in your anti-virus software configuration.